# How to cast a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, casting, pointers, types

```
void foo(void **Pointer);

int main ()
{
    int *IntPtr;

    foo(&((void*)IntPtr));
}
```

Why do I get an error?

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(void*) is not an lvalue, it is kind of a casting operator, you need to have the ampersand to the immediate left of the variable (lvalue).
This should be right:

```
foo(((void**)&IntPtr));
```

Comment: crashmstr: It's required to explicitly cast to void** in C++. If it was a void* you wouldn't need a cast, however it's not void*, it's void**.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I have not had to work with void pointers in a while :)

Comment: well, casting to void** is like casting to int** in that regard. void** is nothing special. the questioner should use void*

Comment: @Johannes, except that foo takes a void** and not a void* which is strictly speaking a type mismatch. And also, it helps to understand the flow, there is little gain of speaking of a pointer-to-a-pointer as a pointer when readability comes into concern.

Answer (score 8):

```
void foo(void **Pointer);

int main ()
{
    int *IntPtr;

    foo((void**)&IntPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
(void*)IntPtr
```

you create a temporary variable, which is only an rvalue, and so can't be dereferenced.

What you need to do is:

```
int main()
{
  int* IntPtr;
  void* VoidPtr = (void*)IntPtr;
  foo(&VoidPtr);
}
```

or equivalent

Comment: However, it is interesting to note that every modification made on Pointer in foo will only affect VoidPtr and not IntPtr (since I guess it was the aim of the OP).

Comment: Yeah, this solution isn't right. You're only copying the (uninitialized) value of IntPtr to VoidPtr in the assignment. You're not making VoidPtr point to IntPtr. You want to do void* VoidPtr = (void*)(&IntPtr);

Comment: That will not work as expected. You need to add the last step of copying the conetent back from VoidPtr into IntPtr

Answer (score 2):

More C++ style:

```
foo( reinterpret_cast< void** >( IntPtr ) );
```

But remember, according to Standard such a cast is implementation specific. Standard gives no guarantees about behavior of such cast.

Comment: That should be "foo( reinterpret_cast< void** >( &IntPtr ) )"

Answer (score 2):

As others point out, you have the order of the cast and the `&` wrong. But why do you use `void**` at all? That means that you accept a *pointer to a void pointer*. But that's not at all what you want. Just make the parameter a `void*`, and it will accept any pointer to some object:

```
void foo(void*);

int main () {
    int *IntPtr;
    foo(&IntPtr);
    assert(IntPtr == NULL);
}
```

That's what `void*` is for. Later, cast it back using `static_cast`. That's a quite restrictive cast, that doesn't allow dangerous variants, unlike the C style cast *(type)*:

```
void foo(void* p) {
    int** pint = static_cast<int**>(p);
    *pint = NULL;
}
```

If the function takes pointers to `void*`, then that function can't accept pointers to `int*`. But if the function accepts either or, then the function should accept `void*`, and you should cast to the proper type inside the function. Maybe paste what you really want to do, we can help you better then. C++ has some good tools available, including templates and overloading, both of which sound helpful in this case.

Comment: I use void** because I have an array of void pointers and the function returns one of the pointers inside void** argument.

Comment: you have a int pointer in your question not an array of void pointers, though.